# Arranging elements with a variable size on a fixed canvas

Tags: css, positioning

Input:
I have created and filled an array/table in velocity. This array currently contains 3 things:

(note that this example is pure fiction)

1. Top level community name (e.g. Stack Overflow USA, Stack Overflow BEL)
2. Subcommunity (e.g. stackOverflow.com/r/USA/CSS and stackOverflow.com/r/BEL/JSON)
3. Owner(s) of the subcommunity (e.g. Frank)

Depending on the situation and the point in time, the amount of top level communities, that have a variable number of subcommunities are each owned by a variable number of owners. And, each top level community can also have one or more owners.

(input) table example:

```
SO USA, , Phil
SO USA, CSS, Frank
SO USA, JSON, Marc
SO BEL, CSS, Marieke
SO BEL, CSS, Francis
SO BEL, JSON, Patrick
SO FRA, , Francois
```

output:

I now want to position these communities and sub communities graphically on a webpage like this

[image]

Depending on the amount of subcommunities, the top level community will have a different size, and should therefore be parsed where it fits best on the page (e.g on a 600pxx800px canvas).

Here are my questions:

- does somebody know code that has already been written to solve this kind of problem?
- if not, how would I best tackle this?